# Powershell get latest on a working folder?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to get latest on a specific folder and was wondering how I would do this. I have been reading the MSDN documentation about the Workspace class but unfortunately it doesn't seem to provide any information about how I would go about getting latest of a specific folder.

For example, I have a single workspace but with multiple working folders. My PowerShell script can get latest but only at workspace level. Is it possible to get it from a working directory level or at a particular folder level?

Thanks in advance, DS.

*EDIT*
I believe this is possible as power tools is able to do it via right clicking a folder and getting latest. Ideally, want to replicate this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.aspx

The below shows my script in practice..

```
$tfs = .\tfs-get-instance.ps1 -uri $uri
$vcs = $tfs.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
[psobject]$workspace = $vcs.GetWorkspace([System.Environment]::MachineName, [System.Environment]::UserName)
$workspace.Map($sourceFolder, $localFolder)
$result = $workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem($sourceFolder);

if ($result -ne "")
{
    echo $result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [Workspace.Get Method (String[], VersionSpec, RecursionType, GetOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139316.aspx) to get what you want.

On the other hand, if you don't necessarily want to do it using the .NET objects, you could let tf.exe do the actual work, like the following:

```
& $TfExePath workfold /map "$codePath" "$LocalFolderPath" /collection:"$tfCollection" /workspace:$workspaceName
& $TfExePath get "$codePath" /version:$ChangeSet /force /overwrite /all /recursive $workspaceName
```

On the other hand, if you have the TF PowerTools installed you should also have PowerShell cmdlets for working with TFS. I have never used them, but I'm guessing you should be able to use them instead of using tf.exe if you want to. I would probably go for the PowerShell cmdlets in the power tools if they fill your need.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using the TFExePath :) the Workspace.Get() gets everything in the workspace. The workaround I have come up with is to create a new temporary workspace, map it, get it then delete it.

Comment: The Get method linked above will not necessarily get the entire workspace. The first parameter lets you provide an array of item paths ($codePath). So try using that method and do something similar to `$workspace.Get(@('$/Path/That/I/Want/To/Get'), $versionSpec, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::Overwrite)` (documentation about what you can pass as $versionSpec at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versionspec.aspx). Let me know how it goes.